# Acces to private variable of controller in php

Tags: php, class, variables, controller

I created a controller and some views:

```
Controller
   Private $importantValues;

  Public function1
       Render view2

  Public function2
       Render view3

  Public function3 
       Call function4

  Private function4
       save something in db
end controller


view1
  call function1

View2
  With post call function2

View3 
  With post call function3
```

Why does $importantValues live only in function1 and function2?
In other functions it’s resetted.

Comment: Please add your real PHP code instead of pseudo code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this pseudo-code. I can only guess you extend this controller and overridden methods cannot access private property - visibility for subclasses should be set to `protected`.

Comment: But I don’t want to extend it, only to have values in every methods of controller